# Connecting Metamask to geth

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask

In [here](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015290012-Using-a-Local-Node) it's said we need to run below command line to let Metamask connect to *geth*:

```
 geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain="chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn"
```

I'm running a private blockchain and when I run the above command line it tries to synchronise and it takes a very long time. It looks like it is connecting to a real blockchain network which I don't need right now.

Obviously, I need Metamask, as I want to write my own user interface that can interact with my private blockchain (or smart contract).

**Question**: Do I need to run the above (or any other) command line to let Metamask connect to *geth* when I'm using a private blockchain?

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correctly, To connect metamask to geth:

- Open Metamask
- Click on Networks Tab ( where you see 'Main Ethereum Network')
- If you are running geth on localhost:8080, choose option **localhost:8080** from the dropdown. Else,
- Choose option **Custom RPC** from the dropdown
- Enter RPC address and Port of geth node inside New Network input box (eg, http://localhost:8013)
- Your metamask is connected with your geth node